# How are error terms calculated for moving average model in R

Tags: r, arima, moving-average

For an ARIMA (0,0,1) model, I understand that R follows the equation:
xt = mu + e(t) + theta*e(t-1)
(Please correct me if I am wrong)

I assume e(t-1) is same as the residual of the last observation. But how is e(t)  calculated?

For example, here are the first four observations in a sample data:
526 658 624 611

These are the parameters Arima(0,0,1) model gave:
intercept = 246.1848
ma1 = 0.9893

And the first value that R fit using the model is: 327.0773

How do I get the second value? I used:
246.1848 + (0.9893*(526-327.0773)) = 442.979

But the 2nd fitted value given by R is : 434.7928

I assume the difference is because of the e(t) term. But I do not know how to calculate the e(t) term.

Comment: I'm not sure I undestood your question. Do you want to know the calculations that yield the residuals from an ARIMA(0,0,1) model? If so, please post the last, say 5, values of the original series and residuals.

Comment: Not the residuals.. I want to find the fitted values. What would be the 2nd value fitted by ARIMA (0,0,1)?

Comment: Several of the questions under "Related" in the sidebar to the right -> are duplicates or near-duplicates. e.g [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/26024/moving-average-model-error-terms), or [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/64033/how-do-i-estimate-the-e-t-from-a-moving-average-model)

Answer (score 5):

You could obtain the fitted values as one-step forecasts using the innovations algorithm. See for example proposition 5.5.2 in [Brockwell and Davis](http://www.springer.com/statistics/statistical+theory+and+methods/book/978-0-387-97429-3); downloable from the internet I found [these slides](http://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~bartlett/courses/153-fall2010/lectures/10.pdf).

It is much easier to obtain the fitted values as the difference between the observed values and the residuals. In this case, your question boils down to 
obtaining the residuals.

Let's take this series generated as an MA(1) process:

```
set.seed(123)
x <- arima.sim(n = 150, model = list(ma = 0.4))
fit <- arima(x, order = c(0,0,1), include.mean = TRUE)
resid <- residuals(fit)
```

The residuals, $\hat{e}_t$, can be obtained as a recursive filter:

$$
\hat{e}_t = x_t - \hat{\mu} - \hat{\theta} \hat{e}_{t-1}
$$

For example, we can obtain the residual at time point $140$ as the observed value at $t=140$ minus the estimated mean minus $\hat{\theta}$ times the previous residual, $t=139$):

```
macoef <- coef(fit)[1]
mu <- coef(fit)[2]
as.vector(x[140] - mu - macoef * resid[139])
# [1] 0.7742192
# equal to
residuals(fit)[140]
# [1] 0.7742192
```

The function `filter` can be used to do these calculations:

```
resid.v2 <- filter(x = x - mu, filter = -macoef, method = "recursive")
```

You can see that the result are very close to the residuals returned by `residuals`. The difference in the first residuals is most likely due to some initialization that I may have omitted.

```
head(cbind(resid, resid.v2))
#            resid     resid.v2
# [1,] -0.39447063 -0.429102263
# [2,]  1.62425953  1.675613161
# [3,]  0.03344943  0.001881606
# [4,]  0.16839438  0.181951010
# [5,]  1.71983927  1.714147387
# [6,]  0.43595315  0.438334539
tail(cbind(resid, resid.v2))
#             resid   resid.v2
# [145,] -0.4803322 -0.4803322
# [146,] -1.4432094 -1.4432094
# [147,]  0.7463573  0.7463573
# [148,]  2.0810053  2.0810053
# [149,] -1.3126564 -1.3126564
# [150,]  0.8601761  0.8601761
```

The fitted values are just the observed values minus the residuals:

```
require(forecast)
head(cbind(x - resid.v2, fitted(fit)))
# [1,]  -0.02526549 -0.05989712
# [2,]  -0.20897584 -0.15762221
# [3,]   0.69211011  0.66054229
# [4,]  -0.02445992 -0.01090329
# [5,]   0.05263269  0.04694081
# [6,]   0.70860766  0.71098905
tail(cbind(x - resid.v2, fitted(fit)))
# [145,]   -0.6911888  -0.6911888
# [146,]   -0.2309088  -0.2309088
# [147,]   -0.6431427  -0.6431427
# [148,]    0.2942704   0.2942704
# [149,]    0.8656695   0.8656695
# [150,]   -0.5872494  -0.5872494
```

In practice you should use the functions `residuals` and `fitted` but for pedagogical purpose you can try the recursive equation used above. You can start by doing some examples by hand as shown above. I recommend you to read also the documentation of function `filter` and compare some of your calculations with it. Once you understand the operations involved in the computation of the residuals and fitted values you will be able to make a knowledgeable use of the more practical functions `residuals` and `fitted`.

You may find some other information related to your question in [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/26024/moving-average-model-error-terms?rq=1).